# Is there a workaround for CloudKit storing its private database on the user's iCloud account?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudkit

Similar to this post: [Is privately-stored data in CloudKit stored on the user's iCloud account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40830320/is-privately-stored-data-in-cloudkit-stored-on-the-users-icloud-account).

*I was wondering if there is a way to bi-pass this, so that individuals iCloud accounts aren't being charged?..*

My team is in the process of designing an MVP iOS SaaS app. We are planning to charge businesses for the data (photos and videos) users are storing on their phones. We are thinking of tracking this via the businesses url, similar to slack's workspace url. And are not sure if CloudKit is the right fit for this use case.

We are want to see if anyone had **any recommendations on backend/cloud services to start out with** that also won't been a major pain scaling from in the future.

CloudKit seems to have a lot of added native value, I can just see it potentially hindering the business model in the future for being able to charge businesses data amounts per a "workspace".

Is there a workaround for CloudKit storing its private database on the user's iCloud account?

Or would you recommend a different cloud service/backend all together (*such as EC2, PostgreSQL, Firebase, Firestore, GCP..*)?

Thanks,
Zack

Comment: CloudKit can only store data in one of two places, the user's person iCloud storage or your app's public iCloud storage (shared between all,users of your app). It doesn't sound like CloudKit is a good fit for your use case. Recommending another service is off-topic.

Comment: @Paulw11, thank you for this input. Would you recommend any specific services for me to look into for this use case?

Comment: Google Firestore is very popular as a NoSQL document store.  You could use Google storage buckets for things like photos and videos with Firestore to hold a document that refers to the file in the bucket.  You could also use Amazon's equivalent or host a MongoDB instance somewhere...